# How to achieve right result from a table list

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The **goal** is to retrieve this result below:

```
MaterialNumber ExpiryDate Quantity
-------------- ---------- --------
11111          10-12-2011 50
11111          10-18-2011 100
11111          01-15-2012 500
22222          11-18-2011 0
22222          05-01-2012 200
33333          12-17-2011 200
33333          04-01-2012 -275
```

The **problem** is that I don't know now how to achieve this result based on my existing code further below.
I also having problem with calculation.

```
SupplyID MaterialNumber ExpiryDate Quantity
-------- -------------- ---------- --------
1        11111          10-12-2011 100
2        11111          10-18-2011 700
3        11111          01-15-2012 500
4        22222          11-18-2011 250
5        22222          05-01-2012 475
6        33333          12-17-2011 200
7        33333          04-01-2012 300



RequestID MaterialNumber RequiredDate Quantity
--------- -------------- ------------ --------
1         11111          10-01-2011   50
2         11111          10-14-2011   600
3         22222          10-17-2011   400
4         22222          04-02-2012   125
5         33333          12-22-2011   175
6         33333          01-10-2012   400


CREATE TABLE TC74_Supply
(
    SupplyID INT IDENTITY,
    MaterialNumber VARCHAR(5),
    ExpiryDate DATE,
    Quantity INT
)
GO
INSERT INTO TC74_Supply(MaterialNumber,ExpiryDate,Quantity)
SELECT '11111','10-12-2011',100 UNION ALL
SELECT '11111','10-18-2011',700 UNION ALL
SELECT '11111','01-15-2012',500 UNION ALL
SELECT '22222','11-18-2011',250 UNION ALL
SELECT '22222','05-01-2012',475 UNION ALL
SELECT '33333','12-17-2011',200 UNION ALL
SELECT '33333','04-01-2012',300

CREATE TABLE TC74_SupplyRequest(
    RequestID INT IDENTITY,
    MaterialNumber VARCHAR(5),
    RequiredDate DATE,
    Quantity INT
)
GO

INSERT INTO TC74_SupplyRequest(MaterialNumber,RequiredDate,Quantity)
SELECT '11111','10-01-2011',50 UNION ALL
SELECT '11111','10-14-2011',600 UNION ALL
SELECT '22222','10-17-2011',400 UNION ALL
SELECT '22222','04-02-2012',125 UNION ALL
SELECT '33333','12-22-2011',175 UNION ALL
SELECT '33333','01-10-2012',400
```

My source code below that is not completed yet

```
SELECT 
    a.SupplyID, 
    a.MaterialNumber, 
    a.ExpiryDate, 
    a.Quantity, 
    a.test1,
    godis =(SELECT top 1 a.Quantity - c.Quantity
            FROM (SELECT 
                    b.RequestID,
                    b.MaterialNumber, 
                    b.RequiredDate, 
                    b.Quantity, 
                    test2 = DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY b.MaterialNumber ORDER BY b.RequestID) 
                  FROM TC74_SupplyRequest b) c 
            WHERE MaterialNumber = c.MaterialNumber AND a.test1 = c.test2),
    a.lll
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        SupplyID, 
        MaterialNumber, 
        ExpiryDate, 
        Quantity, 
        test1 = DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY MaterialNumber ORDER BY SupplyID),
        lll = 321
     FROM 
        TC74_Supply
) a
```

Comment: can you articulate what the calculation is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

So you have some quickly evaporating stuff on your hands? If you need to sum requests in period starting at last expiry date to current expiry date, you might use this:

```
select *, Quantity - isnull(Demand, 0) Vasted
from TC74_Supply
outer Apply
(
  select sum (Quantity) Demand
    from TC74_SupplyRequest
   where TC74_Supply.MaterialNumber = TC74_SupplyRequest.MaterialNumber
     and TC74_Supply.ExpiryDate >= TC74_SupplyRequest.RequiredDate
     and TC74_SupplyRequest.RequiredDate >=
         (select isnull (max(a.ExpiryDate), 
                            (select min(RequiredDate) from TC74_SupplyRequest))
            from TC74_Supply a
           where a.MaterialNumber = TC74_Supply.MaterialNumber
             and a.ExpiryDate < TC74_Supply.ExpiryDate)
) a
```

I'm curious about '22222'. My numbers don't match yours, and I couldn't find a scenario where I would get exact numbers. The question that I'm trying to ask is: do you have some total of material that expires at certain dates, so that request might be served by few entries in Supply table?